# How to alloc page as anon page in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, alloc

I want to allocate pages as anon page,
but when I use `alloc_page_node()`, pages were allocated as file page.

```
struct page* page;
int node = 0;

page = alloc_pages_node(node, GFP_KERNEL, 0);
printk(KERN_INFO "File page: %d\n", !PageSwapBacked(page));
```

Result: File page: 1

How to allocate page as anon page?

Comment: Anon pages can still have swap.